# Mutating Calling Objects in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Can someone explain why this prints "goodnight"? If you removed

```
string = "hello"
```

It would print "goodnight world" .

```
def a_method(string)
  string = "hello"
  string << " world"
end

bedtime = "goodnight"
a_method(bedtime)

puts bedtime
```

I understand that << mutates, but not why adding the = hello makes such a big difference?

Comment: Because ruby is pass-by-value. So the method `a_method` is not mutating the original reference to the string `"goodnight"`

Comment: In your case it comes down to your use of `<<`, which modifies the object instead of just returning a changed version. If your method instead had `string + "world"` this wouldn't happen.

Comment: @user1875195 if `a_method` was not mutating the original reference to the string `"goodnight"` then it would not print `"goodnight world"`. Concatenating `" world"` to `bedtime` is mutating it.

Comment: @Mike: No, it is not mutating the reference, because that is simply impossible. Ruby is pass-by-value, you *cannot* mutate the reference. It is dereferencing the reference and then mutating the object the reference points to. The difference between variables and the objects referenced by them is fundamental, not just in Ruby, but in any language.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Yes I was not thinking carefully enough about my wording when I said "original reference," I meant the object the original variable was referencing, as you said. But just to split hairs, doesn't this mean Ruby is **not** pass-by-value? How can `a_method` know the memory location that `bedtime` is referencing if that information is not passed along when `a_method` is called? You said yourself that it is derefencing the reference and mutating the object the reference points to. How does that reference exist inside the scope of `a_method` if Ruby is pass-by-value?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Oh I see. Pass-by-value must not imply that a reference is not passed (pass-by-value and pass-by-reference are horrendously misleading names). The reference is definitely passed in Ruby, you just can't change which object the reference points to inside the scope of the method. As opposed to copying the object to a new location and passing a reference to that new object, which would be a much more accurate outcome for pass-by-value. But to be perfectly clear and technical, I don't see how you could argue that Ruby is not pass-by-reference when a reference is clearly being passed.

Comment: @Mike: It's not called "pass-a-reference", it is called "pass-by-reference". In other words, it is not about *what* is being passed, it is about *how* it is being passed. And the reference is being passe by value. Note also, that you are confusing two different instances of the term "reference", which mean two different things in two different contexts. the word "reference" in "pass-by-reference" does *not* mean the same thing as the word "reference" in "the reference is being passed". You could maybe replace the term with "pass-by-variable" and "the pointer is being passed".

Comment: @JörgWMittag Okay after reading several explanations I finally get it. And I do see why "passing a reference for the object" is not the same as passing the original reference that points to the object. Also, I discovered there is an enormous amount of confusion generated on the Internet because the names "pass-by-reference" and "pass-by-value" are so misleading. At some point one must wonder whether the mass confusion is worth perpetuating those names just for history's sake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby there's a difference between *in-place* operations and those that return a copy. Sometimes the name provides a hint, like `gsub` vs `gsub!`, but other times you just need to know, like `<<`.

What you're doing here is redefining which object `string` references so no permanent modification is made to the original reference.

The line `string = "hello"` does not mean that the original `bedtime` object reference changes.

If you wanted that effect you'd do `string.replace("hello")` which is an in-place reassignment of the string's content.

To find out what object you're referencing call `object_id` on the object in question. You'll notice here that with your code that value changes, but with `replace` it does not.

Ruby method arguments are passed by *object reference* which in practice is a lot like a pointer. If you're expecting that value to be passed by absolute reference that's not the case.

Comment: This sort of blows my mind. How does one know whether a given method is an "in-place" operation? Besides writing out a code example like the one in the question.

Comment: @Mike It's often necessary to read the documentation and look carefully at the description. [`Array#push`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-push) modifies in-place, many of the Array methods do without any hint like `!` presumably due to tradition, it behaves the same as JavaScript, Python and others. Other classes are more explicit about their intent, like String with `gsub` vs. `gsub!`. Until you know for sure, read the documentation to check.

Comment: `String#replace` is *not* re-assignment, it is mutation, in exactly the same way `String#<<` or `String#gsub!` is. Variables aren't objects, you can only call methods on objects, therefore you cannot call methods on variables, therefore a method call cannot re-assign a variable. Only `=` can re-assign a variable. (Modulo reflection using `Binding#local_variable_set`, which as you may notice is not a method on variables (because variables aren't objects) but on bindings and does not take a variable as argument (because variables aren't objects) but a symbol denoting the name of a variable.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag I mean "re-assign" in the context of the content itself. There's many layers to this particular situation.